# How to show 'No Record found' if table is empty?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am new in cakephp 3. Now, I am fetching data from database which is successfully show all table data but I want to show 'No record found' message if table is empty. So, How can I do this ?Please help me.

Controller: PostsController

```
<?php
    namespace App\Controller;
    use App\Controller\AppController;

    Class PostsController extends AppController {
        Public function index(){
            $this->set('data',$this->Posts->find('all'));
        }
    }
?>
```

Layout: Index.cpt

```
<div class="row">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                if(!empty($data))
                {
                    foreach($data as $row)
                    {
            ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row->title; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->description; ?></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
            <?php
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<p>No record found</p>'; 
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You are doing an if/else based on whether the variable is empty already, so what exactly is the problem? (`tbody` must contain table rows as children of course, so you should probably not output a naked `p` at this point.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `find('all')` method in cakephp return object, it wont be empty if check normally.

Instead of

```
if(!empty($data))
```

Try this line

```
if (!$data->isEmpty()) {
```

Should work.

Please find updated documentation [link](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/6483).

Comment: I use this and it show 'unexpected 'else'' @Rahul Meshram

Comment: Error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) 
File D:\xampp\htdocs\boost\src\Template\posts\index.ctp 
Line: 25

Comment: You are missing curly braces somewhere, debug. I am 100% sure. This snippet can't be the only code in your template

Comment: Yes :) @Rahul Meshram I forgot to remove extra curly braces. Thank You